Как посчитать сколько уникальных товаров в списке с заказами
Всем привет. Есть такой запрос:
select product_id, order_id,product_ids,name from 
courier_actions 
left join (select *, unnest(product_ids) as product_id from orders) t1
using(order_id)
left join products
using(product_id)
where action='deliver_order'

который соединяет таблицы и дает вот такой результат:

Задача: как посчитать сколько каждого товара в целом списке НО если в заказе два одинаковых товара то считать их за один
Нужно что бы было так:


Оберните это все во внешний селект вида select count(distinct product_id) from (...)

Мне не заказы нужно посчитать а товары

А где вы видите подсчет заказов? Если результат не тот, дополните вопрос ожидаемым результатом

не так объяснил, спасибо, дополнил

И откуда вылез time_purchased? Что это и как оно относится к предыдущей выборке?

вот его и нужно посчитать. Это сколько раз товар заказывали (но если в одном заказе товар встречается два раза то считать за один)
Другими словами нужно посчитать самые популярные товары

Тогда примерно так: select product_name, count(*) from (<inner select>) group by product_name. Из предоставленной выборки, похоже, что в одном заказе не может быть дублей товаров

такие случаи в выборке есть (все не влезает в картинку)
но вариант:
select product_name, count(*) from (<inner select>) group by product_name
не подходит так как он считает все товары без разбора, а мне нужно что бы считал - если в заказе два и больше одинаковых товара то считать их за один

Тогда нужны данные из таблиц в виде INSERT и DDL схемы самих таблиц(CREATE), что бы можно было их загрузить в какую нибудь песочницу и поиграться. + указать, какую СУБД используете

Еще вариант - сначала сгруппировать выборку по товарам + номеру заказа, а потом уже считать заказы(группировать по ним и считать количество)

Спасибо, последний совет помог
